# Python, How do I correctly indent my results using format?

Tags: python

Currently I have my results showing as such:

```
Digit     Count     %
1         5738      29.4
2         3540      18.1
3         2342      12.0
4         1847      9.5
5         1559      8.0
6         1370      7.0
7         1166      6.0
8         1043      5.3
9         904      4.6
```

The code I used for printing this is:

```
print("Digit", "   ", "Count", "   ", "%")
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, "       ", num_count[i], "    ", format(num_count[i]/total_num*100,".1f"))
```

And I want my result to be:

```
Digit     Count     %
1         5738      29.4
2         3540      18.1
3         2342      12.0
4         1847      9.5
5         1559      8.0
6         1370      7.0
7         1166      6.0
8         1043      5.3
9         904       4.6
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `\t` (tabulator)

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi That won't work for large numbers. For instance: when printing: 990 99 and then 1000 100

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`tabulate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)

```
>>> import tabulate 
>>> header = ['Digit', 'Count', '%']
>>> tabulate.tabulate([[i, num_count[i], num_count[i]/total_num*100] for i in range(1, 10)], headers=header, tablefmt='grid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a tab seperator?

```
print("Digit", "\t", "Count", "\t", "%")
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, "\t", num_count[i], "\t",format(num_count[i]/total_num*100,".1f"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tab separator won't work for large numbers.

The solution is to set number of digits you want to print for each variable in the print statement. Like in this example:

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    print("%8d\t%s" % (i*10, i))
```

To demonstrate why tab separator will fail, if you run this code:

```
for i in range(1,1000):
   print("%s\t%s" % (i*10, i))
```

You will see that when it reaches 990 the formatting jumps right:

```
970 97
980 98
990 99
1000    100
1010    101
```

Using tabulate is also a possibility, but this is more straight forward and provides a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using tabs, you can also use str's `.ljust`method to fill in spaces for a total of certain characters:

```
print(str(i).ljust(7, " "), 
      str(num_count[i]).ljust(7, " "), 
      format(num_count[i]/total_num*100,".1f"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of each column, you can use string formatting:

```
print("{0:<5s) {1:<5s} {2:<5s}".format("Digit", "Count", "%"))

for i in range(1, 10):
    print("{0:<5d) {1:<5d} {2:<3.2f}".format(i, num_count[i], format(num_count[i]/total_num*100,".1f")))
```

In this example, we're assuming that the digits column will have a maximum of 5 digits, the count column will have a maximum of 5 digits, and the % column will have a maximum of 3 digits to the left of the decimal point, and 2 digits to the right of the decimal point. More information here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax